# Can I output my computer's video signal into the cable lines in my house?

Tags: video

Would it be possible to hook my computer's video signal into a cable plug in my house, and be able to tune to a channel on any tv in my house (also hooked to the cable system) to see it?

Comment: Do you have a budget and resolution in mind? It would help you get an answer closer to your requirements if you edited your question with some details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - but it is awkward.

You need to get a graphics card with a coaxial output, however I haven't seen these in years.

Again, I haven't seen VGA to Coax adapters in many years, they simply do not have the resolution and people don't want it!

You are much better off getting splitter boxes and wiring up each tv to them, I know this isn't what you want, but standard coax just isn't really up to what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [RF modulator](http://www.google.com/products?client=safari&rls=en&q=rf+modulator&oe=UTF-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=w2U-S9GuOczAjAfV6dHoCQ&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=3&ved=0CCYQrQQwAg) to convert an S-Video signal from your computer to RF, then transmit that around the house. But as Wil says the quality is not great.

If it is only for SD content you may be ok with RF, but for high definition I'd consider an [HDMI-ethernet converter](http://www.octavainc.com/HDMI%20ethernet%20converters.html) over cat-5e, or just running HDMI (ensure it is CL2 or CL3 rated if routing through a wall, see this [question](http://home4film.com/questions/368/is-a-special-hdmi-cable-needed-to-route-through-a-wall) on Home4Film for details). You can get [HDMI faceplates](http://www.datapro.net/products/hdmi-wall-plate.html) if it is a permanent extension, this allows you a bit more flexibility in the connections at each end and looks neater.

Comment: That looks cool too, but still to expensive

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

**[Grandtec USA GWB-4000 Ultimate Wireless PC to TV Converter](http://www.pcmall.com/p/Grandtec-USA-Connectors/product~dpno~969126~pdp.bdijcfj)**:

> The Ultimate Wireless is the world's
>   first truly wireless PC-to-TV
>   converter. Convert resolutions up to
>   1600x1200 and transmit the display to
>   any TV within 100 feet of your PC.

of course this gadget takes care of your audio signal as well!

Comment: That's really cool but way too expensive